# Can I use gets() and puts() of same string in different functions

Tags: c, function, struct, gets, puts

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee
{
    char ename[20];
    int sal;
};

struct employee accept(struct employee);
void display(struct employee);

void main()
{
    struct employee e,f;
    f=accept(e);
    display(f);
}

struct employee accept(struct employee e)
{
    printf("Enter employee name and his sal :");
    gets(e.ename);
    gets(e.sal);
}

void display(struct employee e)
{
    printf("Employee name :");
    puts(e.ename);
    printf("Employee salary :");
    puts(e.sal);
}
```

The above code is taking the details from the user and not displaying it as it is supposed to do.  Can anyone help me out rectifying it?

Comment: Turn on, and **mind**, your compiler warnings (your function `accept()` is defined as returning a value but it does not have a `return` statement)! Your indentation could be a little better to give an eagle's eye view of the code structure.

Comment: My compiler doesn't gave any warnings and no errors

Comment: If your compiler does not give warning, maybe use another? (maybe it's enough to change command-line switches or configuration or ...)

Comment: You should never use the `gets()` function — it is [far too dangerous to be used, ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: @AdityaBachu are you sure you're running with `-Wall -Wextra` (or whatever your compiler uses to enable warnings)?

Comment: You could sensibly replace `printf("Employee name :"); puts(e.ename);` with `printf("Employee name: %s\n", e.ename);` — and similarly for printing the salary information.

Comment: regarding: `gets(e.ename);` and `gets(e.sal);` the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the language around 2009.  Your commiler should have told you about this.  Suggest using `fgets()` (which has a different parameter list, so be sure to read the MAN page for `fgets()`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses the function: `gets()` which has been removed from the C language some 10+ years ago.  Ignoring your compiler messages isn't the way to program

Answer (score 1):

1. `main` should return `int`. Use `int main(void)`.

---

2. `sal` is an `int`, `gets` would be for strings but you shouldn't ever use, it's very dangerous as no destination buffer bounds checks are performed, allowing buffer overflow. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/6865932) by SO C queue legend ;)

   Use:

   ```
   fgets(e.ename, sizeof e.ename, stdin);
   ```

   And:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &e.sal);
   ```

   Note that you should always check the return value of these functions to validate inputs.

---

3. `puts` only parameter is a pointer to char, it doesn't take `int` arguments.

   Use:

   ```
   printf("%d", e.sal);
   ```

---

4. Your `accept()` function should return a `struct employee` but it doesn't.

   Possible correction:

   ```
   struct employee accept(void)
   {
       struct employee e;
       printf("Enter employee name and his sal :");
       if(fgets(e.ename, sizeof e.ename, stdin) != NULL)
       {
           e.ename[strcspn(e.ename, "\n")] = '\0'; // optional, removing \n
       }
       else
       {
           //handle error
       }
       if(scanf("%d", &e.sal) != 1)
       {
           //handle error
       }
       return e;
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   struct employee e;
   e = accept();
   ```

   You can remove `f` as it's not needed.

Comment: `int main(void)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I guess, if we want to be properly pedantic ;)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ahhhh missed that one, and here I was thinking my compliments wouldn't pay off :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return what is read from `accept`.

```
struct employee accept(struct employee e)
{
printf("Enter employee name and his sal :");
gets(e.ename);
gets(e.sal);
return e; /* add this to return things read */
}
```

Also note that:

- `gets()` and `puts()` are for reading and printing *strings*, not integers. `int sal;` in the declaration of the structure should be replaced with something like `char sal[128];`.
- You should add indentation to improve readability.
- `gets()` has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun. It is deprecated in C99 and removed from C11. Instead of that, you should use `fgets()` and manually remove newline character read.

Comment: Note that `gets()` was deprecated in TC3:2007 (Technical Corrigendum 3) — not in the original C99 standard.

Comment: Also, using `gets(e.sal)` reads into an (uninitialized) integer — hardly correct behaviour.  Passing (a copy of) `e` to the function which is then used as a local variable is odd, too.  The argument should be omitted and a regular local variable used and returned.  Or a pointer to the structure can be passed, and the return is then unnecessary (if the function is declared `void accept(struct employee *ep)` and corresponding other changes are made).